# Google Code jam puzzle - Welcome to Code Jam

Tags: algorithm, strings, haskell, complexity

The problem is to count all possible sub-sequences of "welcome to code jam" in a given input string (and only return the last 4 digits of the count).  Here is the [link](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/90101/dashboard#s=p2&a=2) to the problem for reference.

I've implemented a solution in Haskell that worked fine on the examples and small datasets but failed on the large data set. Here is the code:

I'm interested in correctness first. (Am I missing some corner case?) I guess performance can be improved by memoization; and I'd be happy get any other tips on that front too.

w_s is short for welcome_solve: This calculates the total number of sub-sequences.

```
w_s x [] = 0
w_s (x: []) str_xs = length ( filter (\z -> z==x) str_xs ) 
w_s (x:xs) (str_x:str_xs) = if x==str_x
                            then (w_s xs str_xs)  + (w_s (x:xs) str_xs) 
                            else w_s (x:xs) str_xs
```

And here is the code to get the last 4 digits:

```
getLast4 (w:x:y:z: []) = [w,x,y,z]
getLast4 (x:xs) = getLast4 xs
format_solve problem 
         | solution < 1000 = getLast4 $ show $ 10000 + solution
         | otherwise  = getLast4 $ show solution
         where solution = w_s "welcome to code jam" problem
```

Example usage:

```
λ> format_solve "format_solve welcome to codejam"
"0000"
λ> format_solve "wweellccoommee to code qps jam"
"0256"
λ> format_solve "elcomew elcome to code jam"
"0001"
```

Comment: [LCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem#Solution_for_two_sequences) should be adaptable to this problem, if you enumerate all LCS's (see [this section of the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem#Reading_out_all_LCSs)) and only consider LCS's where the length of the match is equal to the length of `"welcome to code jam".

Comment: Can you be any more specific about what the failure is? Wrong answer? Takes too long? Some kind of exception?

Comment: My bad; It fails with wrong answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`w_s`, short for "welcome_solve", is, frankly, a poor name.  You're writing a function that counts the number of subsequences.  It's not even restricted to operating on strings.  Why not call it `countSubsequences`?

```
countSubsequences :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Int
```

Your base cases should be simpler.

```
countSubsequences [] _ = 1
countSubsequences _ [] = 0
```

The recursive case is correct, but could be written more clearly with a more idiomatic convention for parameter names, and using guard clauses.

```
countSubsequences needle@(n:ns) haystack@(h:hs)
  | n == h    = countSubsequences needle hs + countSubsequences ns hs
  | otherwise = countSubsequences needle hs
```

Comment: Hmm.. but it fails on the large dataset. Is there any bug with the logic to get the last 4 digits?